# Stratified sampling with multiple variables in Python

Tags: python, sampling

I need your advice. I am performing stratified sampling in Python. There are 3 variables (A, B, and C), and each of them has 3 levels.

```
A: a1, a2, a3
B: b1, b2, b3
C: c1, c2, c3
```

That being said, there are 3 * 3 * 3 = 27 strata, and for each stratum, I want to random sample 1000 rows. What is the best strategy to implement the code?

Thank you.

Comment: What does your dataset look like? Have you written any code at all so far?

Comment: @Grismar For now, I am using the following strategy, but I am trying to implement the algorithm from scratch
```from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
df_train, df_test = train_test_split(dt, train_size=0.2, stratify=dt[["A", "B", "C"]])```

Comment: Have you had a look at https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/main/sklearn/model_selection/_split.py (line 2481 and onwards)? What exactly are you looking to achieve by writing it from scratch? What have you written so far and what is your specific question?

Comment: @Grismar Thank you for sharing the link. I will go through the code and understand the logic. If needed, then I will update it from my end.